# Scala abstract classes

Tags: scala, abstract-class, case-class

I'm working on a Scala course from Coursera and am having some issues with abstract classes.  Here I'm trying to access fields from case classes of the CodeTree abstract class, but the compiler complains that these fields don't belong to the CodeTree class itself.  I would think that the pattern matching would take care of that but apparently it doesn't.  Any help?

```
abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree

def weight(tree: CodeTree): Int = tree match {
  case Leaf(_, weight) => tree.weight
  case Fork(left, right, _, _) => weight(tree.left) + weight(tree.right)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is right, your abstract class has no instance variables.

The good news is you don't need them, you have already everything you need from the pattern matching of the `tree` input parameter.

Just modify your code into:

```
abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree

def weight(tree: CodeTree): Int = tree match {
  case Leaf(_, weight) => weight
  case Fork(left, right, _, _) => weight(left) + weight(right)
}
```

When you have a successful pattern matching in Scala the variables on the left side of a matching clause are available to the right side of the clause itself, so:

- In your first clause you match a `Leaf` and so you have the `weight` variable available to the right side, which simply returns it
- In your second clause you match a `Fork` and so you have a `left` and `right` variables available to the right side (you discard the `chars` and `weight` variables), which recursively call the  `weight` function

You can refer to [Scala Tour](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) to have a better understanding of how pattern matching works.

Comment: I've added some links and a little explanation of what's going on. I know Scala can be strange at first. :)